# Extraction of data from soil database using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I wanted to extract soil data from harmonised soil database (hwsd) for a small catchment using QGIS. Files that I have downloaded from hwsd database are in .bil,.hdr,.blw and Microsoft Office Access format. And I have shapefile showing boundary of the catchment.

Please give the procedure to extract data for my catchment from database using QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287679/extract-data-from-hwsd-in-qgis