# Use harmonized world soil database (HWSD) in QGIS ie load .blw, .hdr and .stx files coming with .bil raster

Tags: qgis, raster, attribute-table, legend

I am trying to use the data of the HWSD in QGIS.
See: http://webarchive.iiasa.ac.at/Research/LUC/External-World-soil-database/HTML/

How do you get the same result in QGIS as in the viewer ?

More precisely :
It is easy to open the .bil file in QGIS and open a table extracted from the database (HWSD_Q). 
However, I can't figure out how to color each pixel to get the map you can see in the viewer.
[image]
One solution is to convert the raster to polygon (see [extract data from HWSD in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287679/extract-data-from-hwsd-in-qgis)) but this process is really too long and does not provide the expected result.

I guess the map is displayed correctly if the .blw, .hdr and .stx files are loaded in QGIS but is seems that these formats are not supported by QGIS. Futhermore, the "official" legend is very important to me as it shows the links between soils. Open the .bil raster and use Properties -> Style -> Singleband pseudocolor (or others) and classify is not a satisfying method because the process to manualy define the color ramp is too long.

I am using the latest LTR version of QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I have converted the ArcGIS style (.lyrx) of this map
[image]

https://data.apps.fao.org/map/catalog/srv/eng/catalog.search?id=14116#/metadata/446ed430-8383-11db-b9b2-000d939bc5d8

to QGIS style (.qml).

**You can download the qml file from** [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_-HMKq6lx0tw2r3V4PvGTGGeXSrur3cS/view?usp=sharing).

[image]